# How to reference other object properties from within methods?

Tags: php

I get this error when I try to reference a property from a method within another class:

```
Undefined variable: testInfo in
```

testInfo is an object that was initialised earlier in the code with:

```
$testInfo = new TestInfo();
```

I am referencing it with a method in another class with:

```
!$testInfo->test;
```

I can echo $testInfo->test from outside the class and it returns the property. My question is why am I getting this error, and how would I go about fixing it?

Comment: How are you passing the `$testInfo` object to that other class instance?

Comment: with: $testInfo->test;

Comment: Way too little context to answer this. Show a more complete example instead of separate one-liners; it's impossible to tell how these are supposed to work together. Likely problem though: [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: That is how you are _calling_ it. If you never `pass` the variable into the other class instance, it won't be available (as indicated by the error message).

Comment: A quick fix might be writing `global $testInfo;` at the beginning of the method. This will tell PHP that you use the global variable and it won't expect a local one.

Comment: @FlorianRhiem There are almost always better methods than using global variables. The use of globals is generally a bad design decision. If the OP provides more context, we can provide a specific answer that is appropriate for the situation.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Absolutely, OP should use Orangepill's answer, or make `$testInfo` a class member, or in the absolute worst case create singleton class. For a final design, globals are aweful. For a *quick fix* however, for seeing if scope really is the cause of this problem, globals are alright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the global keyword:

```
$testInfo = new TestInfo();

class X {
    function y() {
        global $testInfo;
        echo $testInfo->test;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800753/how-to-reference-other-object-properties-from-within-methods#comment24214040_16800753

Comment: can you explain why that works, setting $testInfo global? by the way Would making the test property in TestInfo class global solve the problem?

Comment: no, global means you're importing the variable from the global scope.

Comment: however it is no a good practice, you should provide more details and code.

Answer (score 3):

`$testInfo` needs to be accessible in the same scope as where it is being used.

Try passing $testInfo into your method

```
  class T {
        public function someMethod(TestInfo $testInfo){
             // do something with testInfo
        }
  }

  $testInfo = new TestInfo();
  $t = new T();
  $t->someMethod($testInfo);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are referencing `$thisInfo->test` from another class, `$thisInfo` doesn't exists in that class' scope. Use `global` keyword:

```
<?php

class TestInfo() {

    public var $test = 'hello';

}

$TestInfo = new TestInfo;

class TestClass() {

    public function getInfo() {

        global $TestInfo;
        echo $TestInfo->test;

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800753/how-to-reference-other-object-properties-from-within-methods#comment24214040_16800753